# Calling function from function WEIRD RESULTS

Tags: javascript, function, synchronization

I was trying to show a text gradually on the screen (like marquee). e.g. H.. He.. Hell.. Hello. when I'm tracing it in debug in VS2010 it's working! but when it's actually running it shows the whole sentence at once.

I made a certain "delay" for about 3 seconds between each letter so it would suppose to take a while, but in reality it's shows everything immediately.

Who's the genius to solve this mystery? (please don't give me advices how to create the marquee effect, it's not the issue anymore. now it's just a WAR between me and javascript!) I'm assuming that it has to do with synchronization when calling function from function?

Thanks to whomever will help me get my sanity back.

you can download the code from here (VS project):
http://pcgroup.co.il/downloads/misc/function_from_function.zip

or view it here:

```
       <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">

//trying to display this source sentence letter by letter:
        var source = "hi javascript why are you being such a pain";
        var target = "";
        var pos = 0;
        var mayGoOn = false;

    //this function calls another function which suppose to "build" the sentence increasing index using the global var pos (it's even working when following it in debug)
     function textticker() {
                if (pos < source.length) {
                    flash();

                    if (mayGoOn == true) {
                        pos++;
                        mayGoOn = false;
                        document.write(target);

                        textticker();
                    }
                }
            }
            function flash() {

    //I tried to put returns everywhere assuming that this may solve it probably one of them in not necessary but it doesn't solve it
                if (mayGoOn == true) { return; }

                while (true) {
                    var d = new Date();
                    if (d.getSeconds() % 3 == 0) {
                        //alert('this suppose to happen only in about every 3 seconds');
                        target = source.substring(0, pos);
                        mayGoOn = true;
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }


            textticker();


        </script>
```

Comment: You should have a look at the `setTimeout` or `setInterval` functions.

Comment: That's not how you do a delay in a synchronous context. Look up `setTimeout`.

Comment: In addition to Sergio's answer, the reason this isn't working is that loops happen more than once a second so d.getSeconds() % 3 == 0 will be true thousands of times every 3 seconds. The reason it works in debugging is that you're slowing down the rate of execution massively. To get it working you'd have to check you're not in the same second as last time. Also this would be UI blocking, so isn't a good idea anyway.

Comment: @mattmanser Actually your comment helped me the most (actually I'd like to pick it as the chosen answer, is it possible to choose a comment?). If you could please explain me what is UI blocking that you mention, when does it accure and why doing this (checking that I'm not in the same second) will cause UI blocking? Thank you!

Comment: @BornToCode I didn't add it as an answer as Sergio's way is definitely the right way to do it! By UI blocking I mean that while the javascript is running the user won't actually be able to do anything on the page, in most browsers I think it'd soon fire a popup saying 'this script is slow, do you want to end it?'. Using setTimeout gets rid of that problem by telling the browser to run the update code once every 200ms (in Sergio's example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're obviously doing it wrong. Take a look at this.

```
var message = "Hello World!";

function print(msg, idx) {
  if(!idx) {
    idx = 0;
  }

  $('#hello').html(msg.substring(0, idx));

  if(idx < msg.length) {
    setTimeout(function() { print(msg, idx + 1) }, 200);
  }
}

print(message);
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/evehus